# Test a method that takes an String argument with JUnit theories

Tags: java, junit, junit-theory

I am very new to JUnit theories. I have a method parse() that takes a html String as an input and returns a Document (DOM of the HTML Document)

```
public Document parse(final String inputString) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (StringUtil.isBlank(inputString))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input HTML String is empty,blank or null");
    return Jsoup.parse(inputString, "", Parser.xmlParser());
}
```

I wanted to write unit tests for this using Junit theories. The boundary cases that I want to check are:

- Empty String
- Blank String (string with whitespaces)
- Null String
- Non Html String
- Valid HTML String

In case of first 3, it should throw an IllegalArgumentException. In case of the last 2, it returns a valid Document Object.
I have been able to write the test for the first 2. But I am not sure how to test the last 3 using Junit Theories.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @DataPoints
    public static String[] function(){
        return new String[]{
                ""," ",null
        };
    }
    @Theory
    public void test(String s) {
        System.out.println("called");
        if(s==null)
            System.out.println("null");
        System.out.println(s.length());
        thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        htmlAssessment.parse(s);    
    }
```

For some reason, the test method isnt called for the argument String = null. Could someone help me with testing the last 3 cases?

Console o/p:

```
called
0
called
1
```

Comment: What is being printed in your console? Isn't `s.length()` throwing an exception itself when `s == null`?

Comment: No, Its not. I added s.length() specifically to test that. It does not call the method test() when s==null. The test() method is called just twice.

Comment: I have no more ideas why this should be happening. Have you tried switching the order of the arguments to see what happens?

Comment: Added null as the second argument instead of third. The tesing terminated after calling test() once. I guess,in this scenario, Junit terminates whenever it encounters null

Comment: I used `@DataPoint` instead of `@DataPoints` and individually asigned the three combinations to different `Strings`. When I do that, it calls the `test()` method even when the String is null. Not sure why it doesnt do that when I use `@DataPoints`

Comment: That's is really weird, I don't know if that's a bug or a feature of JUnit.

Comment: Take out your length check. It might be an NPE is causing an error and timing is preventing you from seeing the log.

Comment: FYI, normal use a `@DataPoints` is `public static String[] value = new String[]{"", " ", null};` There is no need for the method.

Comment: @JohnB : The length check is after the `print("called")` statement. The console should've at leased printed `called` 3 times.Right?

Comment: I have seen in exception cases where the log doesn't make it to the screen before the JVM is shutdown due to an exception. It is just a simple test to make sure.

Comment: @Nemin Would you please unmark this question as answered? As a JUnit user, I would really like to figure out the answer of using `null` in `DataPoints`. Until we get an answer for that, I think this issue is still open.

Answer (score 4):

So I believe this post answers the question about using `null` in `@DataPoints`. [JUnit 4.12 issue when using theory + enum type + DataPoint that contains a null](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/673).

It appears that `@DataPoints` does not use the type of the declared field to determine the type of the `Theory` input. Instead it analyzes each actual value. Because of this `null` is not being linked to `String` but to `Object`. And the premise is that `null` should not be provided to every argument in a `Theory`.

Hence, it appears that you cannot use `null` in `@DataPoints`. As has been pointed out, you would need to use `@DataPoint`. However, rather than having 3 `@DataPoint` values you could do the following...

```
@DataPoints
public static String[] nonNullValues = new String[]{"", " "};
@DataPoint
public static String nullValue = null;
```

However, I do have another solution. Recently I discovered [@TestedOn](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/experimental/theories/suppliers/TestedOn.html). This allows for the following:

```
@Theory
public void testIt(@TestedOn(ints={3,4,5}) int value){...}
```

Unfortunately `@TestedOn` was only implemented for `int`. I implemented my own [@TestOn](https://github.com/dancerjohn/LibEx/blob/master/testlibex/src/main/java/org/libex/test/theories/suppliers/TestOn.java) that allows for all the primitive types. So your test could successfully be written as:

```
@Theory
public void testIt(@TestOn(strings={"", " ", TestOn.NULL}) String value){...}
```

This will correctly test on `null`. I have really liked this mechanism because it allows me to map `Theory` values to individual tests.

Answer (score 1):

When you use @DataPoint instead of @DataPoints and individually assigns the three combinations to different Strings it works and it calls the test() method even when the String is null.

```
@DataPoint public static String input1 = "";
@DataPoint public static String input2 = " ";
@DataPoint public static String input3 = null;
```

PS: @Nemin found the answer to his own question. Just wanted to leave it here so it's easier to find.

PS2: If you know if this is a bug or a feature of JUnit, or if there's another way to solve it keeping @DataPoints, please do share this information here.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to upgrade your **JUnit** to release **4.12**.

The problem was fixed.

See the below URLs for many details:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/529
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md :

> Up until JUnit 4.11 a @DataPoints-annotated array field could contain null values, but the array returned by a @DataPoints-annotated method could not. This asymmetry has been resolved: both can now provide a null data point.